# Browser compatibility IE vs. FF/Chrome/Opera: spacing is off

Tags: html, css

http://www.pachamber.org/www/news/headlines/2011/whatsnew/PA%20Chamber%20joins%20nationwide%20business%20community%20in%20fight%20for%20reasonable%20regulation.php

If you open this site in IE then open it in Chrome or FF, you will notice the gray space on the left hand side. I've been trying to play with the widths on the  tags but still can't get it right.

Can anyone suggest anything?

Thank you.

Edit: Adding link to show the differences:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqZBB.png

Comment: What is it about the gray space that we are supposed to notice?

Comment: if you notice the amount of gray between chrome and ie, it is significantly different.

http://i.imgur.com/x4yLD.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, set:

```
body, html {
    height:100%
}
```

And don't use tables for layouts. The 90's are over.

Comment: Ha, thanks for the advice. It's an old site that I'm bandaging until the redesign. I took your advice and it still looks the same. Thanks again.